# Renaming File names

Tags: php, file, file-rename

I am using the following script to rename images in a folder. When executed the first 2 (new) names are being failed, so it basically starts with 3.

```
    function getFileExtension($filename){   
        return substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.'));
    }
    
        
    $counter    =   1;
    
if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
    
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        $newCounter = str_pad($counter, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $prefix =   '11225';
        $newName = $prefix.$newCounter;
        rename('images/'.$fileName, 'images/'.$newName.getFileExtension($fileName));
        $counter++;
        
    }
    
    closedir($handle);

}
```

These are the warnings I get,

> Warning: rename(images/.,images/11225001.): The process cannot access
> the file because it is being used by another process. (code: 32) in
> C:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\renameimages\index.php on line 21
>
> Warning: rename(images/..,images/11225002.): Access is denied. (code:
> 5) in C:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\renameimages\index.php on line 21

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I think the problem is with the function being called inside `rename()` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two is links to current folder and parent folder. You should skip them.

```
if($fileName=='.' || $filename=='..')continue;
```

Comment: Correct. Just want to add, if you have access to it, I think using [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php) is a better way to implement the loop in general. You have access to methods like `isFile`,`isDot`,`getExtension` that basically do the check you suggest or the extension-parse OP implemented himself.